# Do weapons re-appear as loot in NG+ and on?

Tags: dark-souls

I'm getting on to mid-game on my first playthrough of Dark Souls, no NG+ yet, but a thought struck me.

When I reach NG+, will all those weapon drops re-appear?
Eg, I got the **[Great Scythe](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/great-scythe)**, goto NG+. I know I will still have the Scythe, but will I be able to goto the location it's at (no spoilers) and pick it up again?

I'm asking this because the [**wiki**](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/new-game-plus) (as shown below) doesn't say so.

> ## What changes?
>
> - Most progress is undone (asides from the exceptions listed below in "What stays the same?").
> - Levels need to be beaten again, killed NPCs will be living again, etc.
> - Enemies hit harder, can take more damage, and are harder to kill as a result. Even small enemies can put out a lot of damage, but they also give more souls.
> - You lose all of your Embers. Craft weapons before starting NG+.
> - You lose all of your Keys except for the Master Key.
> - You lose all of your Bonfire Items except for the Bottomless Box. Without the Lordvessel, you can no longer warp, and all of your warp locations are lost. I.E. you will need to find the ash lake bonfire again before you can warp there, even once reaquiring the Lordvessel.
> - You lose the Orange Charred Ring and the Covenant of Artorias ring.
>     Domhnall of Zena sells you Gwyn's armor, the Great Lord's Set.
> - You can offer the Soul of Gwyn, Lord of Cinder at the Altar of Sunlight as a rank +1 member of the Warrior of Sunlight covenant to receive the Sunlight Spear miracle.
> - Rite of Kindling is removed; however, kindled bonfires retain their status.
> - You cannot level up until you get to Firelink Shrine, so try not to lose the souls received from Gwyn, Lord of Cinder before you get there.
> - You can now be infected with Gravelord Black Phantoms, in NG+ or higher.
>
> ## What stays the same?
>
> - Enemy behavior remains the same, but with higher stamina and damage output, they may appear to be more aggressive at times.
> - You keep your equipment, stats, souls, and items (except for the items mentioned above).
> - Your Estus Flask level stays the same.
> - You keep your covenant and rank.
> - Bonfires keep their status. Bonfires kindled three times in the first playthrough will have the same status in NG+ and provide the same number of flasks.
> - Oscar, Knight of Astora gives you the Big Pilgrim's Key regardless of New Game iteration, after you've killed the Asylum Demon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All items found by picking them up from the ground can be found again.

Without it, there would be no way to get duplicates of some spells. Also, it would be a weird if they reset the drops for things removed from your inventory but not other things (some embers and keys)

Source: I have beaten the game through NG+++ and know it happens.

Comment: Awesome! Because I was going to fire enforce my Great Scythe and wanted an electric one as well for my other hand when I get to NG+.